# Signalling server performance issue: Python vs NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, django, webrtc, django-channels

I'm developing a WebRTC application that requires a specific signalling server implementation. Initially I was developing the server in NodeJS but then I decided to migrate to Python (using Django Channels AsyncWebsocketConsumer to communicate with the clients through Websockets). After the migration I used the WebSocket benchmarking tool Thor to compare both implementations and these are the results obtained (5000 websocket connections, each one sending 1000 messages):

**Python (Django Channels) Implementation:**

```
class SignallingConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.peer = None
        self.signal = None
        self.is_peer_registered = False

    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        pass
```

**NodeJS implementation:**

```
method.start = function () {
    this.webServer = this.createWebServer();

    this.webServer.listen(this.config.port, function (){
        console.log("Web server is listening");
    });

    this.socket = this.createWebSocket(this.webServer);
    this.socket.on('connection', function(ws) {

        var pingsCompleted = 0;

        ws.on('message', function(evt) {

        }.bind(this));

        // Set out ping/pong mechanism
        var pingInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if(pingsCompleted > 2) {
                ws.close();
            } 
            else {
                ws.ping();
                pingsCompleted++;
            }
        }.bind(this), config.pingPeriod);

        ws.on('pong', function(evt) {
            pingsCompleted = 0;
        }.bind(this));

        ws.on('close', function(evt) {

        }.bind(this));
```

**Python (Django Channels) Results:**

```
Online               30792 milliseconds
Time taken           30792 milliseconds
Connected            3714
Disconnected         0
Failed               1286
Total transferred    4.43MB
Total received       525.91kB

Durations (ms):
                     min     mean     stddev  median max
Handshaking          4795    11410      5517   10824 23923
Latency              NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN NaN
```

**NodeJS Results:**

```
Online               41307 milliseconds
Time taken           41307 milliseconds
Connected            4051
Disconnected         0
Failed               949
Total transferred    952.72kB
Total received       693.4kB

Durations (ms):
                     min     mean     stddev  median max
Handshaking          2       1124       1044     860 5200
Latency              NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN NaN
```

So altough the number of failed connections is more or less the same in both implementations, the duration of the handshake negotiation in Django Channels is much slower than in NodeJS, which made me reconsider the migration for Python.

So are these results normal? Is it better to use NodeJS in a case like this?

Comment: I'm also using django channels and I'm intrigued by these results. The difference looks significant, I'll also be looking for community feedback.

Comment: could you elaborate on "that requires a specific signalling server implementation". Are you looking for some particular characteristic?

Comment: Hi @yumoji, 

The server will have to implement some specific business logic besides serving as an intermediary channel during the WebRTC Interactive Connectivity Establishment.

This business logic includes, for example, authenticate the clients according to proprietary certificates and determine which clients can be reached by a given client.

Comment: Why would the amount of transferred data be so different between the two implementations? Also, don't forget to `clearInterval(pingInterval)` after closing the socket.

Comment: I don't know and that is really strange but the thor test was the same for both implementations:
_thor --amount 5000 --messages 1000 ws://localhost:8000_

Comment: Channels appears to impose some sort of overhead. At least that would explain why the amount of data transferred is somewhat proportional to the mean latency. Perhaps overhead would explain both, but the question would then be, overhead for what?

Answer (score 2):

NodeJS does its non-blocking I/O at a pretty low level and is backed by V8, which does pretty good JIT optimisations.

Django channels are a higher-level construct, and performance will also heavily depend on the Python implementation. CPython, among other things, interprets bytecode directly and uses a global execution lock.

I would expect NodeJS to perform better than Django on CPython. However, if you prefer Django for other reasons, you may want to compare performance on PyPy, IronPython and Jython.